# Change the background image of an element

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having some issues with creating a really simple function that's supposed to change the background image of a `div` element to match whatever image is being hovered upon by the mouse.

The HTML  looks like

```
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
```

That's just the `div` element I want to change, alongside one of the images.
So our function is supposed to take in an image element as a parameter. But I'm having a lot of trouble accessing this image parameter's `src` attribute and using that in the `.style.backgroundImage` property.

My current code is:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    var div_element = document.getElementById('image').innerHTML;
    var picurl = "url(previewPic.getAttribute('src'))"
    div_element.style.backgroundImage = "url(picurl)";
 }
```

And this gets me an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundImage' of undefined` on my browser console.
If you can tell, I'm trying to put the actual `div` object into a variable, then put the picture url into a variable. Then I want to use the `.style.backgroundImage property`. This isn't working. But the solution is probably really simple. What could I do to fix it?

Comment: why are you getting innerHTML?? obviously div_element has not style property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. Getting the inner html is just setting your variable to a string representation of what's inside the element, which is nothing since it's an `<img>` tag.
2. Essentially, you're putting everything in quotes, so javascript doesn't do anything with it.

Remove the `.innerHTML` from the first line of the function, and then take the parts javascript needs to evaluate as code out of the quotes.

Change your code to:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
    var div_element = document.getElementById('image');
    var picurl = "url(" + previewPic.getAttribute('src') +")"
    div_element.style.backgroundImage = picurl;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand on some image hover you want to change div background?
I would do it with jquery:

```
$('img').hover(function(){

$('div').css(''background-image:'url("image_link")');

});
```

Comment: There is no jquery tag, and your code won't work because you're messing up the quotes. Not to mention, your answer is only a partial, if the OP doesn't know jquery, he probably doesn't know how to implement your solution into his code.